# SAS iterative loops between two datasets

Tags: loops, sas

I'm stuck with a situation where I have two datasets.

One containing defaults records at customer level, with each line including columns like `ID_customer`, `date_default`, `amount_default`, and a variable equal to `amount_default` which I need as editable variable which I call `left_default`

The second includes the payments, if any, made at customer level to repay these defaults. The variable are similar to the one of defaults, like ID_customer, date_payment, amount_payment and a variable equal to amount_payment which I need as ediatable which I call `left_paymnet`

What I want achive is that the code iteratively go through each lines of the default table, and for each default record it checks in the payment table if there are any payment made by the same customer, with the payment date greater or equal to the one of the default.

The logic is oldeast default get paid with priority  respect to newer

If there is any payment with the above mentioned criteria, then depending on the amount of the payment made then I should populate the default table with new columns, one for each payment until the default amount is fully covered.

At the same time, if the paymnet amount is greater than the default amount left unpaid, then I should update the left_payment column with the amount of payment left after paying the part of the remaining default.

I think with an example is simpler.

Let say we have

```
table default

ID amount_default date_default left_defaullt  
1    5                01012015         5  
1    4                10012015         4  

table paymnet

ID amoutn_payment date_paymnet left_paymnet  
1  3                15122015         3  
1  6                18012016         6
```

So at the first iteration the code first should focus on the first default of 5 euro, and then looking for payments in the payment table should retrieve 3 euro from the first line of payment and 2 euro from the second line of payment. So that after the first iteration the result should be

```
default

ID amount_default date_default left_defaullt payment1 datepayment1  
1  5                01012015       2             3        15122015  
1  4                10012015       4  

payment

ID amoutn_payment date_paymnet left_paymnet  
1  3                15122015      0  
1  6                18012016      6
```

As the first default is not fully paid the second iteration should create the following result

```
default

ID amount_default date_default left_defaullt pay1 date1   pay2  datet2  
1  5                01012015      0             3    15122015  2    18012016  
1  4                10012015      4  

payment

ID amoutn_payment date_paymnet left_paymnet  
1  3                15122015     0  
1  6                18012016     4
```

as the first default if fully paid then the iteration move to the second default

```
ID amount_default date_default left_defaullt pay1 date1   pay2  datet2  
1  5                01012015       0             3      15122015  2    18012016  
1  4                10012015       0             4       18012016  

payment

ID amoutn_payment date_paymnet left_paymnet  
1  3                15122015     0  
1  6                18012016     0
```

So that as final result we know when each part of each default has been paid.

This involve in SAS I suppose two do loops through two datasets but not sure how to put together a similar code as it seems in the web there is no much documentation.

Here an example of the code I'm working on. Pretty sure it has many pieces wrong but as in order to offer a proper view of my issue:

```
data tot_imp;                
   input contract $ nie $ account_type $ fecha date9. missing_pago;  
   format fecha date9.;
   datalines;         
1 xx cc 01SEP2017 5
1 xx cc 04SEP2017 4
;                          
run;  


data pagos;                
   input contract $ nie $ account_type $ fecha date9. remain_pago;  
   format fecha date9.;
   datalines;         
1 xx cc 09SEP2017 3
1 xx cc 12SEP2017 2
;                          
run;  



data tot_imp_el;
set tot_imp nobs=num1;

do k=1 to num1;

partial=0;

do i=1 to num;
set pagos (rename=(contract=con nie=nies account_type=type fecha=fechas)) nobs=num point=i;

if con=contract and nies=nie and fechas>=fecha and remain_pago>0 then do; /* if the pago date is later than the impago and the same pago has not been used for other impagos*/

if missing_impago-remain_pago<=0 then do; /* if the pago pays all the impago */

call symput("cc", partial);
call symput("pago","pago"&cc);
call symput("fecha","fecha_pago"&cc);

partial=partial+1;
&pago=missing_pago;
remain_pago=remain_pago-missing_pago; 
missing_pago=0 ;
&fecha=fechas;
drop con nies type fechas remaing_pago;

leave;

end;

else do;

call symput("cc", partial);
call symput("pago","pago"&cc);
call symput("fecha","fecha_pago"&cc);

partial=partial+1;
missing_pago=missing_pago-remain_pago;
&pago=remaing_pago;
&fecha=fechas;
remain_pago=0;

drop con nies type fechas remaing_pago;

end;

end;

end;

run;
```

Comment: This isn't a question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. We're happy to help work out code that you're working on, but this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Hi Joe, I have an example of code but I'm pretty sure I did many things wrong here. But if it can help I post it here

Comment: I recommend you add a new row for each payment rather than a new column, and add a new transaction id column to keep track of them. This will be much easier to manage.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but isn't getting responses because the desired output in terms of columns isn't what most people would recommend.  But the core question of how to apply payments to the oldest default (and track which default(s) each payment was applied to) is interesting.  If you don't get many responses today or tomorrow, I may try posting a new question which is a revised version of this.  I think it would be too much of a change for an edit.

Comment: I made a new question, which is a revised version of this, structured in a way that makes more sense to me.  I framed it in terms of credit card debits and credits, with long skinny datasets.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009596/credit-card-ledger-assign-credits-to-specific-debits

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a confusing format to put the information in wide rows.  If what you want is basically a running ledger of defaults and payments for each ID, I think it would be easier to keep the data in narrow columns.  For example, below interleaves the defaults and they payments (by ID and Date), and creates a running Balance:

```
data default;
  input ID amount date ddmmyy8.;
  format date date9.;
  cards;
1 5 01012015
1 4 10012015
;
run;

data payment;
  input ID amount date ddmmyy8.;
  format date date9.;
  cards;
1 3 15122015 3 
1 6 18012016 6
;

data want;
  set default (in=d) 
      payment (in=p)
  ;
  by id date;
  if first.id then balance=0;
  if d then do;
    type='Default';
    balance+-amount;
  end;
  if p then do;
    type='Payment';
    balance+amount;
  end;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Returns:

```
Obs    ID    amount         date    balance     type

 1      1       5      01JAN2015       -5      Default
 2      1       4      10JAN2015       -9      Default
 3      1       3      15DEC2015       -6      Payment
 4      1       6      18JAN2016        0      Payment
```

Comment: Hi quentin. Thank you for your response. However i need the association in columns between defaults and payments as each default line could represent a "capital" or " interest"entity, so i need to know if the payment has been used to repay a capital or interest default

Comment: I still like the rows. But my answer dodged the goal of assigning each payment to a specific default. I'll have to think more. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: Quentin, as side question. I see you use the' + ' and '+-' sign combination like a sort of "retain" statement. I have never seen this kand of use of these operator. Can you tell me how it is defined in SAS so I can do some search on this specific use? thanks

Comment: It's a sum statement. `X+1;` is equivalent to `retain x 0; x=sum(x,1);`