# Credit Card Ledger- Assign Credits to Specific Debits

Tags: sas

Inspired by the question [SAS iterative loops between two datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45958638/sas-iterative-loops-between-two-datasets), suppose I have a dataset of credit card debit transactions (purchases) and credits (payments).  I want to create a new dataset which has the running balance (which is straight forward), and assign each credit to a specific debit (the oldest debit which has not been paid off).

Debit data like:

```
data debits;
  input customerID transactID Date mmddyy10. Amount;
  format Date mmddyy10.;
  cards;
1 101 01/01/2017 -10
1 102 02/01/2017 -50
2 103 01/01/2017 -10
2 104 02/01/2017 -50
3 105 01/01/2017 -10
3 106 02/01/2017 -50
4 107 01/01/2017 -10
4 108 02/01/2017 -50
;
```

Credit data like:

```
data credits;
  input customerID transactID Date mmddyy10. Amount;
  format Date mmddyy10.;
  cards;
1 201 01/15/2017 10
1 202 02/15/2017 50
2 203 02/15/2017 10
2 204 02/20/2017 50
3 205 04/01/2017 5
3 206 05/01/2017 20
3 207 06/01/2017 40
;
```

Toe get the running balance, I can interleave them by customerID and Date:

```
data balance;
  set debits  
      credits 
  ;
  by customerID Date;

  if first.customerID then Balance=0;
  Balance++Amount;
run;
```

Which makes:

```
customer    transact
   ID          ID             Date    Amount    Balance

    1          101      01/01/2017      -10       -10
    1          201      01/15/2017       10         0
    1          102      02/01/2017      -50       -50
    1          202      02/15/2017       50         0
    2          103      01/01/2017      -10       -10
    2          104      02/01/2017      -50       -60
    2          203      02/15/2017       10       -50
    2          204      02/20/2017       50         0
    3          105      01/01/2017      -10       -10
    3          106      02/01/2017      -50       -60
    3          205      04/01/2017        5       -55
    3          206      05/01/2017       20       -35
    3          207      06/01/2017       40         5
    4          107      01/01/2017      -10       -10
    4          108      02/01/2017      -50       -60
```

I want to add a variable CreditedDebit.  For each credit, CreditedDebit would be the transactID of the debit which the credit was applied against.  A credit is applied against the oldest debit transaction for that customer with an unpaid balance.  So my WANT dataset is:

```
customer    transact
   ID          ID             Date    Amount    Balance    CreditedDebit

    1          101      01/01/2017      -10       -10      .
    1          201      01/15/2017       10         0      101
    1          102      02/01/2017      -50       -50      .
    1          202      02/15/2017       50         0      102
    2          103      01/01/2017      -10       -10      .
    2          104      02/01/2017      -50       -60      .
    2          203      02/15/2017       10       -50      103
    2          204      02/20/2017       50         0      104
    3          105      01/01/2017      -10       -10      .
    3          106      02/01/2017      -50       -60      .
    3          205      04/01/2017        5       -55      105
    3          206      05/01/2017        5       -50      105
    3          206      05/01/2017       15       -35      106
    3          207      06/01/2017       35         0      106
    4          107      01/01/2017      -10       -10      .
    4          108      02/01/2017      -50       -60      .
```

The want dataset shows that credit 201 was applied to debit 101, credited 202 was applied to debit 102, etc.  Note that some debits are paid late.  Some credits may be applied to multiple debits.  CustomerID=3 paid $20 on May 1 (Transaction 206).  On that date there was $5 left to be paid on Debit 105 and $50 left to be paid on Debit 106. So there are two records in the WANT dataset for transaction 206, showing that $5 was applied to Debit 105 and $15 was applied to Debit 106.

I can't think of a reasonable way to link each credit to the debit it is applied against.  I'm thinking about approaches like "load a hash table (or just an array) with all the debits for a CustomerID, then read through each credit for that CustomerID, applying each credit to the oldest non-zero debit and outputting a record each time a credit is applied to a debit."  But I'm not liking the pseudo-code in my head.

Comment: If a customer applies a credit and ends up with a positive balance, do you want to mark that transaction as crediting subsequent debits or just previous ones?

Comment: @user667489 I was going to add that part as extra credit. :)  I'd say the credit should be split like transaction 206. Part of it would be marked as paying off the previous debit.  For the remainder I would be okay either way (either unmarked because it was an over pay or marked as applying to a future debit).  Your choice.

Comment: The hash table approach seems reasonable. Have you encountered any problems when attempting to implement this approach?

Comment: Honestly haven't tried it yet but I'll give it a shot and post the attempt as an answer. Would you think I could load all debits (for all customers) into a hash table with customer ID as the key that allows duplicates? And then read a credit record and iterate through all the debit records for that ID in the hash table to find the first non-zero one and update it?  Or I suppose I start with the interleaved data I could read through that by customer ID, adding debit records to the hash when encountered and updating when paid or end of by group. That seems easier maybe.

Comment: If you can afford to fit your entire dataset in memory, that would allow you to write some slightly simpler code. Otherwise, some sort of double-DoW + hash should allow you to load the transactions for one customer at a time.

Comment: Thanks. At first I thought a double DoW alone might do it, but then realized I would need a hash or array to manage a queue of debits. It's a three day weekend where I live. Maybe I'll try a couple hash approaches.